# Error with new/old project because of AppCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I know many people have asked this questions previously too. I have gone through almost all the posts available on StackO but all in vain. Trying to make it work since last 24 hours but of no use.

What I have tried till now : 
1.) Fresh copy of Eclipse and ADT
2.) Deleting the .android folder and .metadata(lost all workspace properties :( ) folder.
3.) Reinstalling whole SDK and everything
4.) Deleting and adding projects(my own projects and appcompat projects) multiple times.
5.) Changed properties target platform and done everything possible
6.) etc etc

I'm not facing any issues with Google Play services...

Still getting errors in appcompat project folder and new projects. I have attached few screenshots below. Please if someone knows the exact issue and how to resolve it then let me know as I have already wasted 1 day on this troubleshooting.

The Problems tab is showing these messages : [Click Me](http://pastebin.com/jLy8Z3af)

[Screenshot-1 http://tinypic.com/r/2hdocjb/8](http://tinypic.com/r/2hdocjb/8)

[Screenshot-2 http://tinypic.com/r/ht7axg/8](http://tinypic.com/r/ht7axg/8)

[Screenshot-3 http://tinypic.com/r/or0512/8](http://tinypic.com/r/or0512/8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Android has updated all the styles and have removed the previous styles from AppCompat.

The solution is ( Recommended ) either to Update everything in SDK and update your project styles with new appcompat-21.

Other solution is to get older version of appcompat and use that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems not finding Material theme, *Project Build Target* of library project appcompat is checked on Android 5?